# How to correctly change objects inside a function?

Tags: c++, multithreading

In my application I have a thread run an object's function. In the function some elements of the object are changed, however I am unable to see these changes in my main thread.

I feel like I may not be altering the correct object. Is this accurate?

**Thread:**

```
thread_.emplace_back(&Philosopher::Live, philosopher_[i]);
```

**Return:**

```
Philosopher::_state current_state_;
current_state_ = philosopher_[i].ReturnState();
```

Comment: Unless `philosopher_[i]` is a pointer, you are passing a copy. Try adding a [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: To little code here. And do you know about locks (mutex or anything)?

Comment: @Tas Yeah that was the problem, I've put `std::ref` around `philosopher[i]` and now everything works. Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

You are likely facing one of two problems*, and without a [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) I can't tell you for sure which it is.

## You are passing a copy

Because there is no context and declaration of `philosopher[i`] I can't know for sure, but you may be passing a copy. Consider:

```
struct Philosopher 
{
    void Live();
    int ReturnState();
private:
    int state;
};

std::vector<Philosopher> philosopher_;
philosopher_.emplace_back(...);
std::vector<std::thread> thread_;
thread_.emplace_back(&Philosopher::Live, philosopher_[i]); // A copy of Philosopher is passed
...
int state = philosopher_[i].ReturnState(); // philosopher[i] has not changed.
```

However, if the `std::vector<Philosopher>` was a `std::vector<Philosopher*>` then you would not be passing a copy (hence why it's hard to see without the declaration of `philosopher_`. **If** you have declared `philosopher_` as a `std::vector<Philosopher>`, you can fix it with [`std::ref`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/ref) or by passing a pointer:

[`std::ref`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/ref):

```
std::vector<Philosopher> philosopher_;
...
thread_.emplace_back(&Philosopher::Live, std::ref(philosopher_[i])); // A reference is passed
```

Pointer:

```
std::vector<Philosopher> philosopher_;
...
thread_.emplace_back(&Philosopher::Live, &philosopher_[i]); // A pointer is passed
```

## You have not locked your object, and haven't allowed your thread a chance to run

Credit to @deviantfan for pointing out this next point in the comments. Consider:

```
struct Philosopher 
{
    void Live();
    int ReturnState();
private:
    int state;
};

std::vector<Philosopher> philosopher_;
philosopher_.emplace_back(...);
std::vector<std::thread> thread_;
thread_.emplace_back(&Philosopher::Live, std::ref(philosopher_[i]));
// There is no guarantee that by the time the code reaches here, Philosopher::Live would've had a chance to run and finish.
int state = philospher_[i].ReturnState();
```

You may not have allowed `Philosopher::Live` a chance to run and finish. You can deal with this in a multitude of ways, but I will only cover "waiting for the thread to finish".

```
std::vector<Philosopher> philosopher_;
...
thread_.emplace_back(&Philosopher::Live, std::ref(philosopher_[i]));
thread_[i].lock(); // Wait for the thread to finish
int state = philospher_[i].ReturnState();
```

This may or may not be desired depending on what you are trying to accomplish. If you want to learn about some other ways, consider reading about [`std::mutex`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/mutex) and [`std::conditional_variable`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/ref)

*I realise at the time of writing this that *you* have solved *your* problem; however, this is just an in-depth answer aimed at helping people with similar problems (plus you may learn something new!) It seems like you may wish to use [a mutex](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/mutex) to employ thread-safety.